# Fetch entity data without a find JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring, jpa, hibernate.

Let's say I have a @ManyToMany relationship, and I have updated the owner of the relationship in the following way:

```
entity.getRelationshipOwners().addAll(_relatioshipOwners);
for (RelationshipOwner relationshipOwner : _relatioshipOwners) {
    relationshipOwner.getEntities().add(entity);
    irelationshipOwnerRepository.save(relationshipOwner);
}
```

Now, the object `entity` is in the detached state although it has been persisted on the database.
I don't want to get the persisted entity with a "find" on the database, it will add overhead.

Is there a way to fetch the persisted entity without looking for the entity in the database?

Comment: That is what `getReference` is for, or rather the `get*` methods on the JPA repository, they return a proxy and don't go to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll go with the getReference

Comment: The `getReference` is on the `EntityManager`, using `getById` from the `JpaRepository` will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of`irelationshipOwnerRepository.save(relationshipOwner);` and get your `entity` because this method returns an entity that you save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).